# Email Scheduler in C# using WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, email, scheduling

I have following scenario: I want to write a WCF service which will distribute emails. Web application will make request to WCF service (hosted in iis) to send email and will provide all data i.e subject, email message, email time etc.

Whenever a request comes to WCF service, it will check either to send email in real time i.e send email right now or it needs to be scheduled, e.g. send email at 5 pm or send email daily 5 pm or send email every week 8pm etc. Also email sending mechanism should be asynchronous so that service give response back to application immediately.

How can I handle it using multithreading e.g. send email in separate thread and return response from service?

Service should also be able to retry sending email in case of failure for n number of times.

I know I can write scheduling logic in separate in windows service using Quartz.Net. But I am bound to do that in WCF service

Comment: It may not be a very good idea to do this in a WCF service. Your remark on doing it through a Windows Service would be more appropriate. You can use the WCF service to receive calls from external systems and add these requests to a data store / queue. Have a Windows Service monitor the queue and perform the actual sending of emails.

Comment: Check out http://hangfire.io/ for an easy way to do this without services/tasks/wcf